# Why does OleDb ExecuteScalar method return Decimal when querying for COUNT?

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I am querying an Oracle 10g database using OleDb.

My query is very simple, just getting a COUNT of records from a given table.

In using ExecuteScalar, I ran into conversion errors trying to convert the result value to Int. In checking the type, it turns out to be System.Decimal.

Now, I've seen elsewhere users having similar issues with IDs, but in this case I am simply returning a count that is expected to be an Integer, so why would I still have to cast it?

The SQL is below.

```
 _sqlText = @" select count(*) as num_records from ce_quote_ext 
        where ce_quoteid in (select ce_quoteid from ce_quote where opportunityid in 
        (select opportunityid from ce_quote where ce_quoteid = '?' )) and custsign = 'T' ";
```

Comment: Look at the oracle driver specs that is used. It may specifies super types for numbers and other types for compactness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really the Oracle OleDb library that's returning a decimal. This is correct behavior. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A96160_01/client2.htm#1155437) for the Oracle documentation. In the example in the Oracle documentation, they are casting the return of a COUNT() function into a decimal. So, it appears by design.

```
// C#
...
CmdObj.CommandText = "select count(*) from emp";
decimal count = (decimal) CmdObj.ExecuteScalar();
...
```

Comment: This is what is tripping me up.

The MSDN docs for ExecuteScalar shows the return value unboxed to Int32. There is no specific reference to the provider and it's potential impact on the return type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar(v=VS.71).aspx

That being said, my provider is a custom OleDb data provider. There is no indication that I am using an Oracle database, and it's not using the Oracle .NET assemblies. So while the Oracle doc describes it one way, I expected the other. Thoughts?

Comment: Thoughts... documentation sucks? : ) In all seriousness, what exactly is the problem? You don't want to cast the object?

Comment: Not a problem now, just curiosity.